# use of jquery siblings for multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

Can I use multiple different elements with inside siblings() in jquery?
and what would be the best practice in jquery to select sibling and can you also please explain why?

Comment: The answer to each/all of your questions is:  Depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please add more details like HTML and CSS in a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) at best in a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can put in parentheses of the siblings the types of sibling elements you want, for example:

```
$("div").siblings("h2, p")
```